# Why can't I add a body to an http redirect?

Tags: http, redirect, go

Here is what I've tried:

```
w.WriteHeader(301)
w.Write([]byte("Redirecting..."))
w.Header().Set("Location", "/myredirecturl")
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", contentLength) // I thought this might help
```

It won't add the `Location` header for some odd reason.
Why isn't it possible to add a body and redirect golang's http package?

Comment: Why do you want to set a body in a redirect? The client wil probably ignore the body and just follow the `Location`.

Comment: @LutzHorn, e.g. see the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_redirect#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) with a 301 and a body.

Comment: Also note that [`http.Redirect`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Redirect) follows the RFC2616 recommendation of [putting a simple body for GET requests](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=38049:38117#L1357). If that's all you need you could just call it; or you could look at the source to roll your own version with a custom body.

Comment: @DaveC, Yes I read that part of the RFC, and I saw the go implementation, but I need a custom body with the redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in the [`net/http`](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter) package:

> #### type ResponseWriter
>
> ```
> type ResponseWriter interface {
>     // Header returns the header map that will be sent by WriteHeader.
>     // Changing the header after a call to WriteHeader (or Write) has
>     // no effect.
>     Header() Header
>
>     // Write writes the data to the connection as part of an HTTP reply.
>     // If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
>     // before writing the data.  If the Header does not contain a
>     // Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set to the result of passing
>     // the initial 512 bytes of written data to DetectContentType.
>     Write([]byte) (int, error)
>
>     // WriteHeader sends an HTTP response header with status code.
>     // If WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write
>     // will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK).
>     // Thus explicit calls to WriteHeader are mainly used to
>     // send error codes.
>     WriteHeader(int)
> }
> ```

The above states that you cannot change `Header()` after a call to `Write()` or `WriteHeader()`.  You should change your code to the following:

```
w.Header().Set("Location", "/myredirecturl")
w.WriteHeader(301)
w.Write('Redirecting...')
```

Comment: Thanks! but, if you test this on chrome and view the Network pane, chrome won't show any body :\ (it would output: "Failed to load response data")

Comment: @funerr https://play.golang.org/p/CPWIVR0_sk works for me with Firefox but I think it's up to the browser (and add-ons and settings)  if it displays the body or just follows the redirect quietly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that once you call Write or WriteHeader, the headers get flushed to the client. Anything headers set after that will get ignored. So just changing the order of commands will fix this:

```
w.Header().Set("Location", "/myredirecturl")
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", contentLength) // I thought this might 
w.WriteHeader(301)
w.Write('Redirecting...')
```

Comment: Like I commented in Tim's answer, the body isn't shown in the chrome Network when I view the redirect response.